# Ruby on rails tasks automation in Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-7, automation

I'm looking for a tool or gem or something to allow me to run ruby methods every certain time.

I've tried many ways to do this like backgroundRB, whenever and starling and workling, the main problem is that we have to automate the tasks in Windows 7, we can't use cron.

BackgroundRB is not being updated, so we can't install it in ROR 3.0.3 or 3.0.9

What I need to do is to monit an event, using rake from the outside takes too long to load and will produce a timeout in a secondary system, so i need to run the methods from the 'inside' without loading all the environment every time.

There are many articles about this, but most of them are not updated, so I need a current suggestion, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the built in Windows Task Scheduler and batch or VBScripts? Even powershell could work.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't find a better solution, I was trying to use windows services. Anyway I'm somehow clustering some servers to ensure availability (http://nlakkakula.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/10-steps-for-deploying-your-ruby-on-rails-application-on-a-windows-server-2008-apache-mongrel-cluster/). It is not nice, but it is Windows. Thanks!